# Perform axios request with SSL certificates React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ssl, axios

I'm try to query Puppet DB API (https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/api/query/tutorial.html) using the SSL certificates for authentication. So in my component called Version.js I did the following (not complete code):

```
import fs from 'fs';
import axios from 'axios';
import https from 'https';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

let versionAPI = 'https://puppetdb:8081/pdb/query/v4/version';


let agent = new https.Agent({
    cacert: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem')
});

class Version extends Component {
getDBVersion = () => {
        axios.get(versionAPI, agent)
        .then(response => {
            const ver = response;
            console.log(ver);
        })
    }
render() {
return (
<Button click with trigger this.getDBVersion()>
);
}

export default Version;
```

This errors out with fs.readFileSync is not a function error:
""TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.readFileSync is not a function""

I found that there is no way I can supply these certs using my front-end code and the only option is to use the node's server.js file with the same code pasted above.

Right now, my server.js is working as a CORS proxy too, can someone help me with making changes to it for the axios request to work as well. I just need some steps to:
1. changes to be done in server.js
2. how to use it in my component making the axios call in my front-end
3. any webpack settings
4. anything else required

The current server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var request = require('request')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'https://' +
    req.get('host').replace('localhost:80', 'puppetdb:8081') + req.url
  req.pipe(request({ qs:req.query, uri: url })).pipe(res);
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

### Adding package.json

```
{
  "name": "front-end_ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^15.4.1",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node src/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:80"
}
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module../src/Components/AgentPages/Version.js
I:/node/front-end_ui/src/Components/AgentPages/Version.js:14
  11 | 
  12 | 
  13 | let agent = new https.Agent({
> 14 |     cacert: readFileSync('./ca.pem'),
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use option [`--https`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps) for webpack-dev-server. Edit your **package.json** section **scripts**. Change `react-scripts start` to

For **Windows (cmd.exe)** `set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start`

For **Linux, macOS (Bash)** `HTTPS=true react-scripts start`

```
import axios from 'axios';

let versionAPI = 'https://puppetdb:8081/pdb/query/v4/version';

class Version extends Component {
    getDBVersion = () => {
        axios.get(versionAPI)
        .then(response => {
            const ver = response;
            console.log(ver);
        })
    }
render() {
   return (
      <Button click with trigger this.getDBVersion()>
   );
}

export default Version;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean that I can run: # node src\server.js --https --cert=../../ssl/server.pem --key=../../ssl/server.pem --cacert=../../ssl/ca.pem. And even if I can run this, what changes do I make to the server.js and how do I initialize that agent connection to the Puppet API and how do I render the GET request API response?

Comment: @reactjs_user **--https** need to use for frontend dev server. Can you show your dev config for frontend.

Comment: I am not using any webpack.config.js file at the moment. My application is a simple SPA which makes a few API requests & renders the content. To authenticate with the API I need to use SSL certificates. I thought it would be easy enough to read a file or pass it as a header or options while doing an axios.get(). If I need to create the webpack.config.js and add some configuration, please let me know.I'm happy to test it.

Comment: @reactjs_user module **fs** is the Node.js and he isn't available in the browser. You just need to send requests with https. Judging by the error with **fs**, you are already using webpack. Please, show your npm command, which run frontend build.

Comment: I'm simply running npm start to bring up my UI. I am not sure how to use module 'fs' in node.js and then make the axios request in front-end using the http.Agent ?

Comment: @reactjs_user You can add your package.json to question?

Comment: Added my package.json to the questions. Thanks for the help! @Alexander

Comment: @reactjs_user I changed my answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: The change you are suggesting will make my front-end application authenticate clients connecting to it over SSL. What I'm looking to do is to make an HTTPS request to an external API using ca, cert & key from my front-end application. Based on what I have found in my searches, I can't do that directly via my front-end. I need to do that using axios in node.js. I'm trying to figure out how to do that and be able to render the data in my front-end. Hope this clears the whole thing. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Also, using the "HTTPS=true react-scripts start" and then running npm start or yarn start errors out with this: I:\node\frontend_ui>yarn start
yarn run v1.21.1
$ HTTPS=true react-scripts start
'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: @reactjs_user HTTPS=true will be used only during development. axios it is only a means to send requests. From which protocol the server installs http or https requests, you do not need to manually send a certificate for this, it is the https protocol for you to do this. If you use Window, change to "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"

Comment: @reactjs_user don't forget to switch to the https:// in the browser bar.

Comment: I ran that with set HTTPS but that doesn't solve my problem. I still get the same error. Please check updated question with the error message.

Comment: Just to clarify on my question again - I am able to send axios request to an external API and render the response in my UI. But another external API that I am trying to use allows only certificate based authentication. So I have the custom CA-signed certificate, private key & the ca.pem files with me. I only want to know how to make the same axios request in my front-end and render the response.